# OpenGL compatibility, naming conventions and ARB vs EXT

Tags: opengl

I thought I had formed a general understanding of how OpenGL naming conventions and extensions worked, until I stumbled upon a case that confused me.

---

Here's my understanding so far:

**No suffix** -- e.g. `glGenBuffers()`. This function is a part of the core profile. The [wiki page](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGenBuffers) tells me that this was added to the core profile starting from version 1.5.

**ARB** -- e.g. `glGenBuffersARB()`. This function is part of the standardized `GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object` extension. The [spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_buffer_object.txt) of this extension clearly declares `GenBuffersARB()` in the "New Procedures and Functions" section. The "Dependencies" section tells me that I can potentially access this from a 1.4+ context, if the hardware supports the extension.

**EXT** -- These are vendor-specific extensions and functions that only some vendors may support. Vertex buffer object doesn't seem to have an EXT extension in the registry.

---

Here's where my understanding breaks down:

`glGenFramebuffers`, as the [wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGenFramebuffers) shows, was added to the core in 3.0.

Now I want to access the frame buffer features at a lower core profile version than 3.0. So I want to use it as an extension. The spec registry tells me that there are two available extensions - [ARB](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_object.txt) and [EXT](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/framebuffer_object.txt).

**Question 1** -- If an ARB extension exists, why does an EXT extension exist? Wouldn't you always choose the standardized one over the vendor-specific one?

A look at the ARB spec in the "New procedures and functions" section tells me that the extension defines the `GenRenderbuffers()` function. No ARB suffix this time. GLEW doesn't have a function prototype for `glGenRenderbuffersARB()` at all. Weird.

The EXT spec does however have a `GenRenderbuffersEXT()` function in the new functions section, and GLEW also has`glGenRenderbuffersEXT()`.

**Question 2** -- Why no ARB suffix if there's an EXT suffix? How does this work for ARB, given that the names of the ARB function and the core function are the same?

**Question 3** -- I ultimately want Framebuffer features from a 1.4 profile. Which extension and which function-set should I use so that I get maximum hardware compatibility coverage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Question 1** -- Usually the EXT version comes first as a collaboration between two or more vendors. ARB extensions require more discussion among voting members of Khronos and can have changes from the EXT version before getting approved. See the GL_ARB_direct_state_access extension which has many changes compared to GL_EXT_direct_state_access.

**Question 2** --
The Issues section of the GL_ARB_framebuffer_object extension states why the functions do not have ARB suffixes:

> (8) Why don't the new tokens and entry points in this extension have suffixes like other ARB extensions?
>
> ```
>    RESOLVED: Unlike most ARB extensions, this is a strict subset of
>    functionality already approved in OpenGL 3.0. This extension
>    exists only to support that functionality on older hardware that
>    cannot implement a full OpenGL 3.0 driver. Since there are no
>    possible behavior changes between the ARB extension and core
>    features, source code compatibility is improved by not using
>    suffixes on the extension.
> ```

**Question 3** --
If you want to use framebuffer objects on a context where the GL version is less than 3.0 you need to look at the extension string:

1. If GL_ARB_framebuffer_object is supported, use the non ARB functions.
2. If only GL_EXT_framebuffer_object is supported, use the EXT functions.
3. If neither extension are supported, you need to fall back to OS level offscreen rendering like pbuffers.